# where to connect the GND of my coaxial cable in the PCB

Tags: grounding

The following picture explain my problem which is related to how connect point A and B to the GND plane of my PCB. All the components are places in the same PCB

[image: schematic]
[case0](https://s21.postimg.org/5bw7qofj7/case0.png)

The first option is to connect the shield of the LEMO directly in the connector location and, in the same way, connect the R to GND in the location of its footprint. The distances between this two point is about 15 mm.

[image: schematic]

In this case the returning current loop of the lemo signal shuld be the shortest; but If i'm not wrong, i cannot compensate the disturbances occuring in the lemo shield.

The next image shows the second option

[image: schematic]

In this case i think that i can compensate disturbances but the loop is bigger.

Can you help me understanding which one of this solution is the best one? and, even better, if there is another solution which i've not considered?

In addition to this problem there is also the problem that the coaxial cable connect two different PCB each one with its own GND. I gave a reading at the 
"Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering" book which take a look at this problem but i find solution which are difficult to implement in this design (like using choke inductor)

Thanks in advance for you help and your suggestions.

Antonio

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd stage of your circuit is a differential amplifier so connect the input resistor with a direct link to the ground point of the input connector - this ensures that other currents (not associated with your signal) will not be able to "add" to your signal due to the non-zero ground plane impedance.